# Efficient way to reuse pre-built dictionary if data is redundant? Deepcopy is too slow

Tags: python, performance, optimization, dictionary, python-2.7

I have a code that involves building a very large dictionary from pre-calculated data (i.e. with many lookups). It uses four-integer tuples as keys and lists of tuples as items. This dictionary is then updated with the appended function for each key (so that each item could be sorted at a later stage). The above process is repeated thousands of times but the original (base) dictionary stays the same. The original dictionary is roughly the same size as the updates (but it varies).

I tried using `deepcopy` and in order to use the original dictionary as "a base" for updating. The copying turned out to be an order of magnitude slower than rebuilding-the entire dictionary from scratch.

If this is unclear, perhaps this simplified code will make more sense:

```
print timeit.timeit('''
for iteration in xrange(10):
    base_dictionary = {(month, day, hour): [(value, 'some_data_name' + str(value)) for value in xrange(10)]
                      for month in xrange(5)
                      for day in xrange(5)
                      for hour in xrange(5)
                      }
    for valuenumber in xrange(10):
        for id_set in base_dictionary:
            base_dictionary[id_set].append((valuenumber, 'some_data_name' + str(valuenumber)))
'''
,
'''
''', number=100)
```

RESULT: 1.30800844321 seconds

```
print timeit.timeit('''
for iteration in xrange(10):
    new_dictionary = deepcopy(base_dictionary)
    for valuenumber in xrange(10):
        for id_set in new_dictionary:
            new_dictionary[id_set].append((valuenumber, 'some_data_name' + str(valuenumber)))
'''
,
'''
from copy import deepcopy
base_dictionary = {(month, day, hour): [(value, 'some_data_name' + str(value)) for value in xrange(10)]
                  for month in xrange(5)
                  for day in xrange(5)
                  for hour in xrange(5)
                  }
''', number=100)
```

RESULT: 13.8005886255 seconds

**It feels very wasteful to rebuild the same dictionary every time I run an iteration. Is there a way to accelerate this process?**

Comment: Can I ask what the use case is? Just seems like a DB would be more appropriate here?

Comment: It's a very large Monte Carlo simulation followed by an optimization/gaming simulation.Ps: the append function I refer to actually appends another value calculated using the previous iteration's results

Comment: You need something between shallow copy and deep copy.  The tuples don't need to be copied because they are immutable.  Perhaps `newdict = {k, v[:] for k, v in olddict.iteritems()}`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, I tried using your method and it seems to be giving faster results in the simplified "sample code" I wrote above, but the speed increase in my program appears to be negligible. However, it does make the code easier to understand for a reader. Thanks

Comment: Ps: @StevenRumbalski It appears no one else is attempting to answer, so I would be glad to accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: Perhaps using a library like numpy would help here? Personally, I ran this code on my machine (my default Python is PyPy) and it came out as 0.35 and 2.1 seconds respectively. If that sort of level would be acceptable to you then I'd suggest looking at ways to avoid Python's object wrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something between shallow copy and deep copy. The tuples don't need to be copied because they are immutable.

```
newdict = {k, v[:] for k, v in olddict.iteritems()}
```